# Dropbox can't find live wallpapers on android phone

Tags: dropbox, live-wallpaper

I would like to add live wallpapers to my dropbox from my android phone but I can't find them. I can find my apps from the backup folder, but how do I find the live wallpapers? I have tried going to the android folder, but it doesn't find anything. At all.

Answer (score 1):

The stock live wallpapers are actually apps found in the /system/apps folder. User installed ones are in /data/app. You will need to be rooted and have a root explorer to access these folders.